# Can I update an Android provider.Settings.System value?

Tags: android

I can read settings like this, for example:

final String mytest = System.getString(this.getContentResolver(), System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON);

...but can't seem to write to settings using putString, no matter what I've tried. Maybe it is the scope of this.getContentResolver()??? I'm a newbie, so who knows, maybe it can't be done, or it's just syntax? Currently the code is in the onCreate of an Activity class.

Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you given your app WRITE_SETTINGS permission in AndroidMainfest.xml?

If not you will see this:

E/AndroidRuntime(11614): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider uri content://settings/system from pid=11614, uid=10053 requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS

I strongly advise looking at the log output when debugging this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks Jim, that was definitely my problem. I was looking at the console window and the debug window in Eclipse, but nothing was popping up. After your comment, I figured I must be missing something... sure enough I found the LogCat window - and there was my Security exception. Thanks again!